# Alert height of window

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the height of the window & document to display through an alert and also when a modal window pops up.  I know I need to use `$(window).height();` & `$(document).height();` but other than that I'm not sure what to do.

**Edit:** The problem that I am trying to solve is that my modal window is adding extra pixels to the bottom of the document so I'm trying to find out the original document height and the height after the modal window is activated.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this

```
alert($(window).height());
```

will show an alert with the height of the window.

Comment: @Rikudo -- OP says: "I'm trying to get the height of the window & document to display through an alert" that is what I answered.

Answer (score 3):

This would alert on load then if the user resizes the window alert again. With a bit more detail on what you want to do we could give a better example:

```
    function alertHeight() {        
        alert("Window Height: " + $(window).height() + ", Document Height: " + $(document).height());
    }

    $(window).load(function() {
         alertHeight();
    });

    $(window).resize(function() {
         alertHeight();             
    });
```